# Receiving projects list using JIRA API

Tags: ios, swift, rest, jira-rest-api

I want make simple JIRA assistant for iOS but cannot figure out why API call return empty array.

For example, using this code i'm trying to get projects list:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: "http://myjira.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project".URL!)
    request.addValue("Basic " + emailAndPasswordAsb64String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    guard let data = data, responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String where !responseString.isEmpty else {
        print("No valid response!", appendNewline: true)
        return
    }

    print("Response: " + responseString, appendNewline: true)

}.resume()
```

But getting this: `Response: []`

I'm also tried to use some other API, for example `api/2/dashboard`, but received this: 
`Response: {"startAt":0,"maxResults":20,"total":0,"dashboards":[]}`

Using `api/2/myself` i received this:
`Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><status><status-code>401</status-code><message>Client must be authenticated to access this resource.</message></status>`

Maybe i missed something and project can be invisible? But for basic authorization i'm using administrator login and password.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

I did two mistakes:

1. `http` is wrong, `https` is right!
2. `emailAndPasswordAsb64String` was created using email and password, it's wrong! User should type in `username` instead of `email`! For administrator account username is `admin` by default.

Hope this will help someone!